# Swift in app purchase not working

Tags: swift

I am making an iPhone game. I am following the Swift In-App Billing tutorial for gaming money settlement. I finished all the Swift coding and build, and I hit the button on the screen but the popup does not pop up. Please let me know what's wrong with my code.

```
 import UIKit
 import AVFoundation
 import StoreKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate,SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {



@IBOutlet var outAddCoins: UIButton! 


@IBAction func btnAddCoins(_ sender: Any) {
    for product in list {
        let prodID = product.productIdentifier
        if(prodID == "Add500000Credit") {
            p = product
            buyProduct()
        }
    }
}


func buyProduct() {
    print("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
    let pay = SKPayment(product: p)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(pay as SKPayment)
}


func addCoins() {
    playerMoney += 500000
    MoneyLabel.text = "\(playerMoney)"
}

var list = [SKProduct]()
var p = SKProduct()






func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("product request")
    let myProduct = response.products
    for product in myProduct {
        print("product added")
        print(product.productIdentifier)
        print(product.localizedTitle)
        print(product.localizedDescription)
        print(product.price)

        list.append(product)
    }

    outAddCoins.isEnabled = true 
}




func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    print("transactions restored")
    for transaction in queue.transactions {
        let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

        switch prodID {

            case "Add500000Credit":
                print("add coins to account")
                addCoins()
            default:
                print("IAP not found")
        }
    }
}






func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    print("add payment")

    for transaction: AnyObject in transactions {
        let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
        print(trans.error)

        switch trans.transactionState {
        case .purchased:
            print("buy ok, unlock IAP HERE")
            print(p.productIdentifier)

            let prodID = p.productIdentifier
            switch prodID {

                case "Add500000Credit":
                    print("add coins to account")
                    addCoins()
                default:
                    print("IAP not found")
            }
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
        case .failed:
            print("buy error")
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break
        default:
            print("Default")
            break
        }
    }
}
```

and this is viewdidload part

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    outAddCoins.isEnabled = false







    if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        print("IAP is enabled, loading")
        let productID: NSSet = NSSet(objects: "Add500000Credit")
        let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        print("please enable IAPS")
    }
    }
```

I am using the latest version of Xcode. I have completed all the configuration for in-app purchases in iTunes Connect, but the purchase pop-up does not pop up after the build. I would appreciate your help.

```
buy Add500000Credit
add payment
nil
Default
add payment
Optional(Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "can not connect to the iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=can not connect to the iTunes Store})
buy error
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Testing in-app purchases is tricky:

- Make sure you have created a sandbox account for testing.
- Test on a device, not in the simulator. You cannot test in the simulator.
- And remember to log out of iCloud on the device before testing. Otherwise you won't be able to use the sandbox account.

Comment: I solved it with your comment.
My problem was not a code error, but a basic problem.
In addition, I think I need to log out of the App Store as well.
Thank you very much.